# Событие на зажатие

Tags: java, android

есть GridView, мне нужно если я зажму,выйдет вспылвающее окно, так вот... Я не знаю,какое событие это делает!

Comment: всплывающее окно с выбором действий?

Comment: Попробуйте OnTouch

Comment: `.setOnItemLongClickListener` - для нажатия на элемент или `.setOnLongClickListener` - для всего GridView (не уверен, что второе сработает)